# Refatorar com eclipse

Tags: java, refatoração, eclipse

Por si só o eclipse  já possui o necessário para refatoração ou vocês indicariam alguma ferramenta para atrela ao editor eclipse e utiliza-lá com mais precisão?

Comment: Faro, bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Sua pergunta é interessante, mas um pouco ampla. Existe alguma necessidade específica que você está precisando? A refatoração funciona de forma diferente para cada tecnologia (linguagem, tipo de arquivo, etc.).

Comment: No momento só uma tentativa pra começar a refatorar as coisas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os recursos de refatoração para a linguagem Java são suficientes para 99% dos casos. Na verdade, em minha experiência, eu nunca precisei usar todas elas.

No entanto, dependendo da tecnologia com que você trabalha, *plugins* adicionais são necessários tanto para edição, auto-completar e refatoração. Exemplos clássicos são *plugins* como o JBoss Tools, Spring Tool Suite e Google GWT, que adicionam características importantes para as tecnologias de cada distribuidor.

Por outro lado, é importante notar que em muitos casos a refatoração automática não é suficiente. Isso ocorre muito quando armazenamos configurações e nomes de classes em Strings ou arquivos *properties*, XML, Json, etc. Neste caso, use a pesquisa em arquivos pressionando <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> na aba `File Search`. Adicione uma pitada de Expressões Regulares, faça as substituições necessárias e você não terá muitas dificuldades.

Answer (score 1):

Depende de quais tipos de refatoração você deseja, o eclipse já vem embutido com as refatorações mais básicas:

- Renomear
- Mover
- Extrair métodos
- Extrair variáveis
- Introduzir parâmetros

[Ver a documentação completa (em Inglês)](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-menu-refactor.htm)

Também existem [diversos plugins](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/refactoring) que podem te proporcionar maior flexibilidade em refatoração, entretanto, por padrão o eclipse já suporta as funções de *refactoring* padrões.

Comment: Ok, agradeço, se souber  de algumas ferramentas e puder indicar eu tÔ aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Existem vários níveis de refatoração. Se for apenas um nome de variável, realmente vale a pena usar os recursos do Eclipse, agora se você precisa de coisas mais aprofundadas recomendo ler o livro a seguir, que a propósito, a Google te oferece de graça :) e em português.
Refatoração (Martin Fowler)

http://books.google.com.br/books?id=zPdb4QJKBtkC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false